# Crashing of Phonegap 1.9.0 application due to _NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, cordova

I am trying to load the HelloWorld Example in Phonegap 1.9.0 using iOS and i am having some problems doing that... I am following this: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS It says Apple Mach-O Linker(Id) Error.

When I click the error, it says:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey", referenced from:
      -[CDVFile setMetadata:withDict:] in Cordova
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I wrote a similar app that doesn't use phone gap and it runs properly... But when i used phone gap, it is giving me this error.. Not sure what to do...Need some guidance.

Comment: are u working in ios,android or what?

Comment: @AamirPathan, do you really needed to ask that? Sad I can't down vote your comment.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In the latest phonegap version: 1.9.0, there is error saying _NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey.

To solve this, add this to AppDelegate.m

```
NSString * const NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey =@"NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey";
```

This will help to solve the error.. Nothing to do with the architecture...

Those who new to PhoneGap can watch these videos:

PArt 1: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zXf1zyKQ5Hw&feature=relmfu

Part 2: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t95KG_SFppU

Comment: I get `warning: unused variable 'NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` using this - where exactly in AppDelegate.m does this line go?